# How to deploy container to ECS+Fargate+CodeDeploy without load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, amazon-elb

I have an app that comes in two pieces:

1. The (Ruby/Rails) main app which is also the web frontend
2. A Sidekiq event handler

The first one is not a problem, done that. CodeDeploy will deploy the new version by creating the new service(s) on the "blue load balancer target group" and start moving the traffic to them in a blue/green setup.

However, Sidekiq doesn't have a port, so no health check. This is the problem I'm having now, the NLB doesn't validate the health of the container, so it keeps restarting and the deploy eventually times out because it can't get a clean service.

I'm not sure if this is a ECS limitation or a CodeDeploy limitation (or a "me limitation" :) ), but it seems I **have** to have a load balancer for that to work.

But something about that just rings wrong! I'm sure AWS *must* have thought about "worker containers", right? How *do* you setup an ECS cluster with two services, each with one task - the two parts above. *And* how do you then use CodeDeploy to deploy to that service/task? Or do you deploy Sidekiq (in this case) in some other way?

Having two services, I can scale them individually.

At the moment, I have a CodePipeline, triggering a CodeBuild to build the image, push that into ECR then trigger CodeDeploy to do the deployment. It worked initially when I had *one* service, with the two tasks, but then both would scale simultaneously which isn't what I want in the end.

Comment: "But something about that just rings wrong! I'm sure AWS must have thought about "worker containers", right?" Yes, just don't configure a load balancer at all on that ECS service. You are the one configuring a load balancer to point to the sidekiq service, just don't do that. Load balancers for ECS services are entirely optional.

Comment: Right, tried that first, but then "all hell broke lose" and it started failing.. Maybe it IS CodeDeploy and not ECS that have a problem?

Comment: "All hell broke lose" is not a detailed error description that we can help you with here. Edit your question to show exactly what you tried, and exactly what error or unexpected behavior you encountered if you want people here to be able to help you.